# Django test discovery fails

Tags: django

I have a bunch of apps, all are inside a `apps` folder.
I'm adding some tests to my project.
It works well, the models / templates / static discovery works super well.
Now I would like to add some tests to my projects, so I created a `tests.py` file inside my app. When I want to run the test (`manage.py test`) it does not work. I have to specify the name of the app to make it works.
I tried with django-nose and I have to same output. I figure out it's because my apps are nested inside a folder but every other django discovery works.

```
ttn_org
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── tests.py <- does not work
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
├── app3
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests.py <- does work
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── celery.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

I have `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))` to add make the apps folder usable

Comment: It's little unclear. Can you also provide simple project structure that describes which tests are running and which don't?

Comment: Can you show your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

I installed `django-nose` and run it with the option `--where apps`